# Why do I get an Access forbidden in Apache?

Tags: apache, windows-7, xampp, http-status-code-403, yii2-advanced-app

Why do I get this error on apache when I access a certain js file??? I tried changing the `httpd-xampp.conf` from `Require local` to `Require local granted` but still to no avail.

I have the right permission to the js file I can even edit it using notepad++.

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14
```

here is inside the `http-xampp.conf` file.

```
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php5_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php5_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php5_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require local granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this section:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Change

```
Require all denied
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

Not the perfect solution imho, but should make your dev environment work.

UPDATE:

Change the enitre section to this:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

This is the default I use (from [symfony.com](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)).

Comment: Might be a stupid question but did you restarted apache after that?

Comment: Yes. Restarted apache. Refresh page. still 403. Restart pc still 403.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that the directory we are talking about (<Directory "C:/xampp/php">) holds the php library, not files available from the browser. You shouldn't change anything there. From what I can read in [xampp faq](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html), question **Where should I place my web content?**, you should put your files in different directories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96776/discussion-between-michal-tomczuk-and-quickbrownfox).

Comment: I figured it out.. I found an error in the script code....  `<script src="/hris/admin/../template/assets/js/jquery-ui.custom.js</script>"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was just a typo in my code....

this causes the error..

```
<script src="/hris/admin/../template/assets/js/jquery-ui.custom.js </script>"></script>
```

doubled the `</script>` tag